# Headset (TSCO-TH5310H) Bluetooth connection problem on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, bluez, bluetooth-speaker

I want to connect my bluetooth headset (TSCO-TH5310H Model) to my ubuntu 16.04.
I search for same problems in other forums they suggest this commands:

---

```
sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-btsco bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-hcidump bluez-tools python-bluez bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev libbluetooth3 python-gobject python-dbus
```

---

I have installed all of them but my problem is that I can pair my device to the computer but it cannot makes connection...
[image]

As you can see connection button is disabled.
    Thank you for your attention! 
               Reza

Comment: Try using terminal. `bluetoothctl` then you should be able to `connect 22:22:22:35:2F:53`  See if any errors show up.  I would expect a bluez.org error to occur.  Use CTRL + d to exit bluetoothctl

Comment: I try that and as you say this response delivered:  
`[bluetooth]# connect 22:22:22:35:2F:53 
Attempting to connect to 22:22:22:35:2F:53
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed`

Comment: @Jeremy31 thank you for your comment, now, after some searches and tries I can connect my headset but a few minutes later ::::::: :'( `Attempting to connect to 22:22:22:35:2F:53
[CHG] Device 22:22:22:35:2F:53 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Controller 74:F0:6D:C6:0D:D3 Class: 0x04010c
[CHG] Controller 74:F0:6D:C6:0D:D3 UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
               ........................                          [CHG] Controller 74:F0:6D:C6:0D:D3 UUIDs: 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 22:22:22:35:2F:53 Connected: no` and then it disconnected.

Comment: @Jeremy31 thank you for your comment, now, after doing `sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` and restarting pulseaudio, I can connect my headset but a few minutes later ::::::: :'( `Attempting to connect to 22:22:22:35:2F:53
[CHG] Device 22:22:22:35:2F:53 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Controller 74:F0:6D:C6:0D:D3 Class: 0x04010c

               ........................                          [CHG] Controller 74:F0:6D:C6:0D:D3 UUIDs: 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 22:22:22:35:2F:53 Connected: no`  these happened and then it disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

For now you can go into settings, Software and Updates, Developer options and enable Pre-released updates from xenial-proposed.  Then after the cache is updated do

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

Then reboot and see if you can connect

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pulseaudio : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1) but 1:8.0-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
 pulseaudio-module-bluetooth : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1) but 1:8.0-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
 pulseaudio-module-x11 : Depends: pulseaudio (= 1:8.0-0ubuntu3)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.`
I attempt to solve it but it appears again.

Comment: You might just want to disable the xenial-proposed and wait for the fix to be released into the main repositories

Comment: Ummmm, this means that I cannot use it until Ubuntu fix the problem and I update my system????